# How to set the Border for a Textview using storyboard in Xcode10 using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a Approver's Remarks TextView in my MainstoryBoard and created an outlet for it  in ApproveViewController.
I am trying to create a border for my Textview using storyBoard and code

1) So First, I have created a class called BorderTextView1. Below is my code for class BorderTextView1

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class BorderTextView1: UITextView {

    var red = UIColor(red: 100.0, green: 130.0, blue: 230.0, alpha: 1.0)

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = red.cgColor
        }    
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = 2
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
            clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

2)And then I have set the custom class as "BorderTextView1" for the textview object in storyboard.

3)so when I run the code, I am able to set the border for the textview in the attribute inspector,

But still I am not able to view the border of Approver's Remarks textview in my simulator. Please provide a solution.

I have attached the screenshot for the attribute inspector selection and the custom class setting.

Setting the Custom class of TextView object

[image: Setting the Custom class of TextView object]

Setting the border colour for textview during Runtime

[image: Setting the border colour for textview during Runtime]

Comment: UIColor value should be less then 1. So divide them by 255 int.

Comment: if you got your answer then please accept it.

Comment: Yes, @Priyavarthini, Kindly accept answer by clicking tick mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below Code, gives following error:

```
var red = UIColor(red: 100.0, green: 130.0, blue: 230.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

> UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug

**Rewrite:**

```
var red = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @McDonal_11. It works now.

Comment: However I am not clear why the colour values must be less than 1? Can you explain this @MRizwan33